# Concatenar columnas en oracle

Tags: oracle

Buenos días. Tengo un problema al concatenar columnas en oracle y no se que hacer. Esta sería una consulta simplificada de lo que hago:

```
select t1.c1 || '##' || t1.c2  || '##' ||  t2.c3 from t1, t2
order by t1.c1 asc, t1.c2 asc, t2.c3 asc;
```

En mi caso la consulta es mucho mas grande, usa muchas mas tablas y concatena muchas mas columnas. Al concatenarlas, oracle me lanza el siguiente error:

```
ORA-01489: el resultado de la concatenación de cadena de caracteres es demasiado largo
```

Hay alguna forma de realizar esa concatenacion sin limitación de caracteres? por ejemplo haciendo uso de funciones clob...

El formato no lo puedo cambiar porque la respuesta la consume un servicio externo y necesita que sean cadenas separadas por dos almoadillas...

Espero me podais ayudar.

Comment: Como recoges el campo? a ver si ese tipo de variable no acepta más de X carácteres.

Comment: a que te refieres ??? no entiendo bien tu pregunta

Comment: Perdona me he confundido :S

Comment: ¿No sería más rápido (menos engorroso) hacer esa concatenación después, en C#, Java o lo que sea que usas? Trabajar con CLOB suele obligar a añadir más código de todos modos

Comment: lo he pensado pero el sqlquery de EF me obliga a indicar un tipo al que mapear y ese tipo lo desconozco, las columnas a mostrar las configuran en tiempo de ejecución los propios usuarios... he pensado usar el tipo JObject de newtonsoft, un object, un dynamic... pero se me cargan vacios

Comment: Hay alguna columna que sea única en tu resultado? (algún id o similar?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un `VARCHAR` o `VARCHAR2` tiene un limite de 4000 caracteres, esto lo podemos verificar así:

```
select RPAD('A', 4001, '0') || 'B' FROM dual;
```

Esto nos dará un error como el que mencionas: `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`. Para evitar esto, tienes una alternativa que es usar la función [`TO_CLOB`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions182.htm)

```
select to_clob(RPAD('A', 4001, '0')) || 'B' FROM dual
```

En este caso el resultado será una 'A' seguida de 4000 `0` más el carácter `B`,  al promover una columna a un objeto `CLOB`, la concatenación completa se promueve a un `CLOB` evitándonos el error. De todas formas este tipo de objetos también tiene su límite, que según la documentación es bastante más amplio:

> Maximum size: (4 GB - 1) * DB_BLOCK_SIZE initialization parameter (8
>   TB to 128 TB)